# Hyperledger Fabric test network chaincode installation Error 500 on windows 10

Tags: docker, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-chaincode

I have installed the Hyperledger test-network on windows 10, following the procedure described in the Hyperledger homepage.
I know it is better ran on Unix/Linux still, I have successfully created the default channel, and the sandboxes for Org1 and Org2 are up.

Continuing the default installation, while attempting to deploy the basic test chaincode I get the following "cannot connect to the Docker endpoint" Error:

$ ./network.sh deployCC -ccn basic -ccp ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go -ccl go
deploying chaincode on channel 'mychannel'
executing with the following

- CHANNEL_NAME: mychannel
- CC_NAME: basic
- CC_SRC_PATH: ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go
- CC_SRC_LANGUAGE: go
- CC_VERSION: 1.0
- CC_SEQUENCE: 1
- CC_END_POLICY: NA
- CC_COLL_CONFIG: NA
- CC_INIT_FCN: NA
- DELAY: 3
- MAX_RETRY: 5
- VERBOSE: false
  Vendoring Go dependencies at ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go
  ~/go/src/github.com/arianagnostakis/fabric-samples/asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go ~/go/src/github.com/arianagnostakis/fabric-samples/test-network
  ~/go/src/github.com/arianagnostakis/fabric-samples/test-network
  Finished vendoring Go dependencies

- peer lifecycle chaincode package basic.tar.gz --path ../asset-transfer-basic/chaincode-go --lang golang --label basic_1.0
- res=0
  Chaincode is packaged
  Installing chaincode on peer0.org1...
  Using organization 1
- peer lifecycle chaincode install basic.tar.gz
- res=1
  Error: chaincode install failed with status: 500 - failed to invoke backing implementation of 'InstallChaincode': could not build chaincode: docker build failed: docker image inspection failed: cannot connect to Docker endpoint
  Chaincode installation on peer0.org1 has failed
  Deploying chaincode failed

Any idea is much appreciated, since i fight with this for a couple of days now...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Chaincode deploying fails on Hyperledger Fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69686333/chaincode-deploying-fails-on-hyperledger-fabric)

Comment: DOCKER_SOCK environment variable is not set.

Answer (score 1):

Solved.
(Thank you @Gelu , @david_k)

The problem was that Docker did not expose the containers correctly to the Git-bash CLI I was using (...)

SO, I tried WSL2: it took me just about 30 minutes to set Ubuntu, install Hyperledger and GO in it and get the sample chaincode up and running.

I did not re-install Docker. I am using Docker Desktop version 4.1.1 (69879), which in Settings-->Resources-->WSL INTEGRATION has an amazing feature of exposing the containers to all WSL-installed distros(!).

The test chaincode runs fast and very smoothly since the very first attempt.